# How to get url id value in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routedata

I want to get the id of my current url and use it in a controller.
http://localhost:14160/?id=69
this `Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]` is returning null value.
Any ideas?

controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int? id = null)
        {
            ViewBag.ID = id;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

controller i want to get the id at:

```
public class FacilityAddController : Controller
    {
 public ActionResult GetID()
        {

           var id= Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];

            return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior .AllowGet);
        }

}
```

Comment: Please post controller code also. You are missing controller

Answer (score 0):

There is no controller name, please add controller name and action name with parameter if parameter is different in routing.

For example:

http://localhost:14160/Home/Index?id=69

http://localhost:14160/Home/Index/69(in case id is defined in routing as optional paramter)

Comment: i am using the default route.Here is my code routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );